Caching from Redis using ASP.NET Core Web API
I am using SQL Server for my database. I want to cache the result from API endpoints because the app is taking too much time initially to load as we have images/audios as files. I have implemented redis in order to cache the result and improve upon initial load time. It is running locally fine, but when I deploy this on the server, it did not show any improvement - rather it delays.
This is my controller endpoint:
[ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "Default604800")]
public class BookController : BaseApiController
{
    private readonly ILogger<BookController> _logger;
    private readonly IDistributedCache _cache;
    public readonly IConnectionMultiplexer _redis;

    public BookController(IDistributedCache cache, IConnectionMultiplexer redis, ILogger<BookController> logger)
    {
        _cache = cache;
        _redis = redis;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("getBooks")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    //[OutputCache(Duration = 604800)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetBooks([FromQuery] BookParams param)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Alhamdulillah. Starting getBooks endpoint....");
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        try
        {
            var cacheKey = $"Books_{param.Status}_{param.PageSize}_{param.OrderBy}_{param.OrderAs}";
            var cachedData = await GetBookFromRedis(cacheKey);
            if (cachedData != null)
            {
                var books = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BookDto>>(cachedData);
                return Ok(books);
            }

            var result = await mdtr.Send(new List.Query { Params = param });

            if (result != null && result.Value != null)
            {
                var pagedList = (PagedList<BookDto>)result.Value;

                var items = pagedList.ToList();

                var serializedBooks = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);

                await StoreBookInRedis(cacheKey, serializedBooks);

                return Ok(items);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("Failed to retrieve books.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
            stopwatch.Stop();
            _logger.LogInformation("getBooks endpoints completed in ${Elapsedmilliseconds} ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }

    private async Task<string> GetBookFromRedis(string cachekey)
    {
        try
        {
            var db = _redis.GetDatabase();
            var cacheData = await db.StringGetAsync(cachekey);

            return cacheData;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error fetching data from redis, {ex.Message}");
            return null;
        }
    }

    private async Task StoreBookInRedis(string cacheKey, string serializedBook)
    {
        try
        {
            var db = _redis.GetDatabase();
            await db.StringSetAsync(cacheKey, serializedBook, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(604800));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error saving on redis, {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

Redis connection is configured in appSettings.json:
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyRedisConStr": "localhost:6379,abortConnect=false",
    ....
}

And I added another configuration and dependency inside program.cs like this:
builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
 {
     options.Configuration = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyRedisConStr");
     options.InstanceName = "SampleInstance";
 });

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(x =>
{
    var connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
    connection.ConnectionFailed += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Redis connection failed.");
    };
    return connection;
});

I have configured serilog to diagnose the performance bottleneck. I am using SQL Server as database.
Any insight/advice for diagnosing issue in production as to why redis is not performing in production while in localhost it is working fine is much appreciated.
My docker-compose.yaml in production is
  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: my-redis
    volumes:
      - ./redis-data:/data
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    environment:
      - REDIS_CONNECTION_STRING=Redis
      - REDIS_MAXMEMORY=5gb
    user: root
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - my-nw


It is unclear why you are manually working with Redis when you have an IDistributedCache.

Hi Alex: i did not find good documentation to implement IDistributedCache. Initially i thought to implement this, but when i checked online people recommend using redis. So its just a redundant line. If you have any source or link to implement IDistributedCache. kindly advise

Distributed Redis Cache

i saw that but thet recommend azure subscription. But is it possible to run in dockerized environment

No, you are not required to use an Azure subscription. You can use a local Redis.

Thanks. But it didnt affected much of performance after implementing this, as per the existing codebase one main api endpoint for get request is fetching around 60K lines of items. Would it be nice to have proxy server like nginx or any other mechanism to reduce latency
